# Using one or the other overloaded creator depending on the arguments available

Tags: c++

I have two constructors for an objects, which use two different sets of data.

```
myclass myobject(set 1);
myclass myobject(set 2);
```

`set 1` and `set 2` are of different types.

I want to create an object of myclass called myobject either with constructor 1 or constructor 2 depending on the set of arguments are available at this point and then use myobject outside of the if statement.

```
if(set1)
  myclass myobject(set 1);
else
  myclass myobject(set 2);
myobject.operation();
```

Can anyone tell me the good way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by `set 1`? this is not valid c++ syntax, are those different variables of the same type? different type? incompatible type? ambiguous conversion sequences? did you try something and get an error? what error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If default construction and copy (or move) assignment are cheap, just use:

```
myclass myobject;
if (set1)
    myobject = myclass(1, 2);
else
    myobject = myclass(3);
myobject.operation();
```

If it is acceptable to allocate things on the heap, use a pointer:

```
std::unique_ptr<myclass> myobject;
// const std::auto_ptr<myclass> in C++03 (it's fine as long as you keep it unique)
if (set1)
    myobject.reset(new myclass(1, 2));
else
    myobject.reset(new myclass(3));
myobject->operation();
```

If you must allocate it on stack, I don't see anyway except using placement new (or changing the constructor to accept both possibilities).

```
#include <new>

char myobject_buffer[sizeof(myclass)];
myclass* ptr;
if (set1)
    ptr = new (myobject_buffer) myclass(1, 2);
else
    ptr = new (myobject_buffer) myclass(3);
ptr->operation();
...
ptr->~myclass();  // <-- use RAII to call this for exception safety
```

Comment: What do you mean by "short enough"? I have tried this : `myclass myobject(set1 ? (argument1, argument2) : (argument3));` but got the error : `error: no matching function for call to ‘myclass::myclass(int)’` (set1 is a bool).

Comment: I think the OP meant that `myclass` has two different constructors, with different parameters.

Comment: Thank you, the first solution is enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the cases where you need to use dynamic allocation, preferably with a smart pointer to keep automatic memory handling:

```
std::unique_ptr<myclass> pmyobject;

if (set1)
{
    pmyobject.reset(new myclass(arg1, arg2));
}
else
{
    pmyobject.reset(new myclass(arg3));
}

pmyobject->operation();
```

`std::unique_ptr` is a C++11 feature, but you can replace it with `boost::scoped_ptr` (which is not the exact equivalent, but is close enough).

You could also use [Boost.Optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html), which can handle this kind of deferred initialization.